# How do I map Area and Iteration paths to a different hierarchy in the target project

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

I'm using **FieldValueMapConfig** to map the source and target Area/Iteration paths, however, the source paths are created at the root of the target project.

How do I set up the config so that the paths are migrated to a new target hierarchy?

For example:

SourceProj\Area1 > TargetProj\**NewParentNode**\Area1

SourceProj\Sprint1 > TargetProj\**NewParentNode**\Sprint1

Comment: Hi @Lymedo, have you succeed this ?

Comment: I've also run into the same requirement and would like some advice.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and regex mapping seemed to work for me, try something like this:

```
{
  "$type": "RegexFieldMapConfig",
  "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
  "sourceField": "System.AreaPath",
  "targetField": "System.AreaPath",
  "pattern": "SourceProj\\\\(.*)",
  "replacement": "TargetProj\\NewParentNode\\$1",
  "valueMapping": { "SourceProj" : "TargetProj\\NewParentNode\\$1" }
},
{
  "$type": "RegexFieldMapConfig",
  "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
  "sourceField": "System.IterationPath",
  "targetField": "System.IterationPath",
  "pattern": "SourceProj\\\\(.*)",
  "replacement": "TargetProj\\NewParentNode\\$1",
  "valueMapping": { "SourceProj" : "TargetProj\\NewParentNode\\$1" }
},
{
  "$type": "RegexFieldMapConfig",
  "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
  "sourceField": "System.NodeName",
  "targetField": "System.NodeName",
  "pattern": "SourceProj\\\\(.*)",
  "replacement": "TargetProj\\NewParentNode\\$1",
  "valueMapping": { "SourceProj" : "TargetProj\\NewParentNode\\$1" }
}
```